RedHat - Permit only specific URLs when using proxy
I want to configure a server to have access to a specific URL. The server is shut out of the network and would need to establish the connection via proxy. I do not want the server to be able to have access to all URLs that are available via proxy. I have no way to configure the proxy itself.
Is there a way to restrict the requests from the server via the proxy to a certain URL or subset of URLs on a RHEL8 system? What would be the best approach to achieve this?
Thank you

Configure the proxy. If that's not feasible, set up a new proxy that you can configure, potentially using the existing one as parent.
